# Use freefall sensor to trigger audio

Tags: linux, audio, sensors, archlinux

I have a Dell Studio 1558, running x86_64 4.5.1-1-ARCH Linux. I noticed that it has a freefall sensor (setup as /dev/freefall) and I was wondering:

What's the easiest way of triggering an audio clip in linux when the sensor detects a fall? (as per https://xkcd.com/1363/)

I also note that a fall is supposed to trigger a shutdown of the HD for protection (the main reason for the sensor) so would I need to keep the sound clip in ram?

Comment: Apologies for posting here, I forgot about unix.stackexchange.com.